# Let $X$ be any nonempty, disconnected subset of $\mathbb{R^{n}}$.

Tags: analysis

Let $X$ be any nonempty, disconnected subset of $\mathbb{R^{n}}$.

Let $U_1$ and $U_2$ be disjoint open sets such that

(i) $X\subseteq U_{1}\cup U_{2}$

(ii) $X_1=U_1\cap X\neq \varnothing$ and $X_2=U_2\cap X\neq \varnothing$.

Suppose $X_1$ and $X_2$ are connected.

Prove that both $X_1$ and $X_2$ are relatively closed and relatively open.

It is clear that $X_1$ and $X_2$ are relatively open.

I'm looking for the closed set $S$ such that $X_1=S\cap X$, but I couldn't find it. Can you help me?

Comment: Recall: a set is closed iff its complement is open

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$X_1$ and $X_2$ are disjoint and their union is $X$. So they are complements of each other in $X$: $X_1=X \setminus X_2$ and $X_2=X \setminus X_1$. Hence, they are closed in $X$.

Answer (score 0):

If you already know that $X_1, X_2$ are relatively open, then you have $X_1 = X\setminus X_2$, and therefore, $X_1$ is closed in $X$ (in other words, it is relatively closed).

---

Note, however, that you didn't provide any proof that $X_1,X_2$ are relatively open.